# Get the category of any app programmatically in Android?

Tags: android

I am working in an application where I am fetch all the application installed my device using this code :

```
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
 mainIntent.addCategory("com.myapp.MY_CATEGORY");
 final List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList =getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
```

Now I want to categories the apps differently **According to their Categories**. Please Suggest me.

Comment: Please take idea from this like regading categories : https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113475?hl=en

Comment: you are adding categories by using `addCategory()` function, so can't you preserve some where those values.

Comment: @Sam-In-TechValens those are categories for listing apps on the market. Intent categories are a whole different beast altogether.

Comment: Can't we separate the apps in different categories. Like Social apps, games apps ?

Comment: You could get the package name, search it on the `PlayStore` and find out which `category` it's listed on the `PlayStore` if at all it's on the `PlayStore`.

Answer (score 2):

To know the category of an application you need to get the data from google play. you can check [android-market-api](https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/). it is a third party api. according to their info

> - You can browse market with any carrier or locale you want.
> - Search for apps using keywords or package name.
> - Retrieve an app info using an app ID.
> - Retrieve comments using an app ID.
> - Get PNG screenshots and icon

So you better check if you can parse the category info using this api.

Answer (score 0):

I realized an AsyncTask to collect categories for some apps, using these libraries:

- android-market-api-0.6
- com.google.protobuf 2.4.1

you can find them on this link:

https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-market-api/downloads

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java

Here's the code in doInBackground() Method:

```
        final ArrayList<MarketApplication> results = new ArrayList<>();
        AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(MainActivity.this.getBaseContext());
        Account[] accounts = am.getAccountsByType("com.google");
        if (accounts.length > 0) {
            try {
                AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> accountManagerFuture =
                        am.getAuthToken(accounts[0], "android", null, MainActivity.this, null,
                                null);
                Bundle authTokenBundle = accountManagerFuture.getResult();
                String authToken =
                        authTokenBundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN).toString();

                MarketSession session = new MarketSession();
                session.setAuthSubToken(authToken);

                Market.AppsRequest appsRequest = Market.AppsRequest.newBuilder()
                        .setQuery(params[0])
                        .setStartIndex(0).setEntriesCount(10)
                        .setWithExtendedInfo(true)
                        .build();


                session.append(appsRequest, new MarketSession.Callback<Market.AppsResponse>() {
                    public void onResult(Market.ResponseContext context, Market.AppsResponse
                            response) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.getEntriesCount(); i++) {
                            MarketApplication marketApplication = new MarketApplication();
                            Market.App app = response.getApp(i);
                            marketApplication.setName(app.getTitle());
                            Market.App.ExtendedInfo extendedInfo = app.getExtendedInfo();
                            marketApplication.setCategory(extendedInfo.getCategory());
                            results.add(marketApplication);
                        }
                    }
                });
                session.flush();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return results;
```

Category information, got from ExtendedInfo, and name of application are added to a custom class `MarketApplication`. `params[0]` is a query String, like app name of interest. 
There is a wiki page that helps developer to make a specific query:

https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-market-api/wikis/HowToSearchApps.wiki

take notice that this service requires to add these permissions in the Android manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```